# How to trigger an action on a controller without the page changing

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a Partial View in my main View listing a number of items.
Razor has correctly produced this partial view for me and has inserted action links (using the @Html.ActionLink command) pointing at an action at a controller and sending in the correct id.
All that works but I wish it to stay like that and not have to return anything!

Right now I am forced to send back something (Content, View, Redirect etc) which changes the main view and I don't want that.

All I want to do is to take action on the server and leave it at that.
What else can I do?

Thanks

```
@model IEnumerable<PopupForm.Models.BOExplorerItem>

<h3>Explorer (partial)<br />
    There are @Model.Count() explorer items.
</h3>

<ul class="ulexplorer">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="boitem">
                <h5>@item.FullName [<i> @item.Code </i>]</h5>
                <span>Level: @item.Level</span>
                @Html.ActionLink("Select", "SelectEntity", "Explorer", new { code = @item.Code }, null)
            </div>
        </li>
    }

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is listen to the click event of link and make an ajax call instead of the normal redirect behaviour. Let the ajax call intitate what code you want to execute.

So change your link like this to apply a css class to our links so that we can use it as our jQuery element selector.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "SelectEntity", "Explorer",
                            new { code = @item.Code }, new { @class="ajaxLink"})
```

Now some javascript to bypass the click event

```
$(function(){
  $("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){
    var _item=$(this);
    e.preventDefault();  //prevent default behaviour
    $.get(_item.attr("href");
  });
});
```

If you want your Action method to execute normal (return View /Other content) on normal non-ajaxified request, you may add an if condition checking to see whether the request is ajax or not

```
public ActionResult SelectEntity()
{
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
    //Execute your method and return a Json result to keep the compiler happy.
    return Json(new {Status="Success"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
     //Return the normal view,
     return View();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - since this is a Partial View - where, when and how do I invoke the javascript?

Comment: Just add the script to the main page (or another javscript file which is included in the main view)

Comment: Did that but it is not working - I put a 'debugger' statement in the code (after the click handler) and it is not being called (the 'debugger' I put after the function does get called).

Comment: It's a bit like here within stackoverflow - the 'vote up' and 'vote down' arrows on the left side of the answer represent I presume what I am after.  There can be many answers listed and when I click one of them they fire off a signal to the server and update themselves within the page.

Comment: Changed the scripts about it a bit and now the ajax code is being called but an error occurs on the e.preventDefault() statement - 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDeafult'  - If I comment this line out it actually calls my controller - so nearly there but because the default is not prevented it blanks out my screen!

Comment: ARGHHHHH -- it was mistyped !!  e.preventDeafult(); in the midst of lots of code looks perfectly reasonable - all ok now!! :)  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Marcel: My bad. It is a typo. Going to fix it for future visitors. Glad this helped you.